# Negative lookahead searching for integers in text

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract all integers from a text that are not followed by the `°` character. I understand I should use negative lookahead, but I could find a regex only for the case when numbers were *following* a certain character.

Say the text is this one:

```
s = "DeBakey 45° Thing 456DeBruyne Blah 45."
```

the expected result is:

```
['456', '45']
```

My closest attempt is `r"(?<![0-9])[0-9]+(?!°)"` which produces:

```
['4', '456', '45']
```

but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You may use a negative lookahead: `r'\d+(?!.*°)'`

Comment: You need `r"[0-9]+(?![\d°])"` which is a shortcut of ``r"[0-9]+(?!\d|°)"``, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WeHbg9/1).

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew. That's exactly what I was looking for! As I understand, it looks ahead and checks that the next character is not a `°` and is not a digit.